# How to capture image from webcam in selenum webdriver c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, flash

I have to capture image using webcam and save as profile image.

Below is the screenshot of my flash application

[image].

Below are the steps I have to perform:

1. Click on allow
2. click on capture
3. click on save

Comment: Use a tool to automate Windows GUI, such as AutoIT

Answer (score 1):

In your case the flash allow button is the hardest part, because its not in the [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp), it is something outside of the browser. Something you cannot interact with with Selenium.

What I have done in the past is programmaticly take a screenshot of the desktop, look for a partial image (which is the button), return the coordinates of the button and then click on that location. Here is my code which I used for VB.Net, you should be able to port it to C#: https://github.com/nreijmersdal/CodedUI/blob/master/ImageLocator.vb

This is called [Image-based Recognition Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17461/is-there-a-name-for-automated-tools-that-work-from-screenshots-like-sikuli-or-mo/17498#17498) and there are frameworks that can do this for you.

For example you cab use the [.Net version of Sikuli](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sikuli4net/), which is a framework to find partial screenparts and interact with them. But I thought this was a bit heavy since it starts a Java Jetty server, since the original [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) is written in Java. It was more lightweight to write a very basic version myself. Still it would do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Link for Java solution http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testing-flash-selenium-flash-javascript-communication/

Info about tool: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html

Haven't found for C#, try to read this Flash automation using Selenium RC

Comment: Could you please provide context to your answer beyond only a link that way when/if the link goes dead the Answer will still be valid?

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are not done in Flash, I would recommend excluding the pop-up from tests altogether.

This can be achieved by setting the specific website to "Always allow" access to camera, using [Flash Player Settings Manager](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html) under the tab "Website Privacy Settings". Of course, those settings are stored locally, so this configuration would need to be done as an extra step of testing environment setup process.